# How to loop over certain files within a directory that belongs to certain samples

Tags: linux

*This question was also asked on [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9572854/)*

I have two samples where the sequencing was done on 3-lanes paired end reads. The two samples are A44943_1 and A44944_1.

I would like to generate a for in loop to merge the R1 files of sample A44943_1 from the 3-lanes,  and then do the same for R2 files of this sample, then I want to merge R1 files of sample A44944_1 from the 3-lanes and then do the same for R2 files of this sample. So I thought about for in loop. My fastq files looks like:

```
R0480-S0001_182602S1P1_A44943_1_H77YFDRXY_CGCAACTA-GAATCCGA_L001_R1_trimmed.fastq
R0480-S0001_182602S1P1_A44943_1_H77YFDRXY_CGCAACTA-GAATCCGA_L001_R2_trimmed.fastq
R0480-S0001_182602S1P1_A44943_1_H77YFDRXY_CGCAACTA-GAATCCGA_L002_R1_trimmed.fastq
R0480-S0001_182602S1P1_A44943_1_H77YFDRXY_CGCAACTA-GAATCCGA_L002_R2_trimmed.fastq
R0480-S0001_182602S1P1_A44943_1_H7YKTDRXY_CGCAACTA-GAATCCGA_L003_R1_trimmed.fastq
R0480-S0001_182602S1P1_A44943_1_H7YKTDRXY_CGCAACTA-GAATCCGA_L003_R2_trimmed.fastq
R0480-S0002_182602S1P2_A44944_1_H77YFDRXY_CACAGACT-TGGTACAG_L001_R1_trimmed.fastq
R0480-S0002_182602S1P2_A44944_1_H77YFDRXY_CACAGACT-TGGTACAG_L001_R2_trimmed.fastq
R0480-S0002_182602S1P2_A44944_1_H77YFDRXY_CACAGACT-TGGTACAG_L002_R1_trimmed.fastq
R0480-S0002_182602S1P2_A44944_1_H77YFDRXY_CACAGACT-TGGTACAG_L002_R2_trimmed.fastq
R0480-S0002_182602S1P2_A44944_1_H7YKTDRXY_CACAGACT-TGGTACAG_L003_R1_trimmed.fastq
R0480-S0002_182602S1P2_A44944_1_H7YKTDRXY_CACAGACT-TGGTACAG_L003_R2_trimmed.fastq
```

Could you advise me on  a for in loop to do this task?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can certainly use a for loop for this if desired, but an easier method is to use the `cat` command - something like this:

```bash
cat R0480-S0001_182602S1P1_A44943_1_H77YFDRXY_CGCAACTA-GAATCCGA_L00[123]_R1_trimmed.fastq > R0480-S0001_182602S1P1_A44943_1_H77YFDRXY_CGCAACTA-GAATCCGA_R1_trimmed.fastq
cat R0480-S0001_182602S1P1_A44943_1_H77YFDRXY_CGCAACTA-GAATCCGA_L00[123]_R2_trimmed.fastq > R0480-S0001_182602S1P1_A44943_1_H77YFDRXY_CGCAACTA-GAATCCGA_R2_trimmed.fastq
cat R0480-S0002_182602S1P2_A44944_1_H77YFDRXY_CACAGACT-TGGTACAG_L00[123]_R1_trimmed.fastq > R0480-S0002_182602S1P2_A44944_1_H77YFDRXY_CACAGACT-TGGTACAG_R1_trimmed.fastq
cat R0480-S0002_182602S1P2_A44944_1_H77YFDRXY_CACAGACT-TGGTACAG_L00[123]_R2_trimmed.fastq > R0480-S0002_182602S1P2_A44944_1_H77YFDRXY_CACAGACT-TGGTACAG_R2_trimmed.fastq
```

Comment: Holy s**t, have I been missing out all along? TIL, thank you @Scot!

Comment: I can relate, @RamRS!  I love to learn a new trick... and bash is full of them. :)

Comment: This is news to me too so I had to look this one up.  Evidently it's part of bash's "pathname expansion" feature set, just like `*` (and so, distinct from "brace expansion" in that it depends on what files are present; so like, `cat [123].txt` expands to `cat 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt` if those are present, but is just `cat [123].txt` if not, versus `{1..3}.txt` which always expands).  Very handy, thanks Scot.